# Identify story about time-travelling assassin that can kill by touching people

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Please help me identify a short story about a time-travelling assassin.  His
time machine is a car.  He gets assignments over the car radio from "The
Oracle."  His 2 henchmen are named Chubb and Harley.  He can kill by touching
people.  Sounds like it was written in the 60s because an assignment takes him to a sort-of hippy cult house, a bit like Charles Manson.